# How to append row from one dataset to another dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to add one row from dataset ds to dc every time. and I want to keep updating the Gridview to bigger the table. But when I  try it in my code. the Gridview can only display one row according to what i input in the textbox.

```
public partial class TestGridview : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int count = 0;
    DataSet dc = new DataSet();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string text = TextBox1.Text;

        SqlConnection con = new              SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XMLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        // Create the command object
        string str = "SELECT * FROM XML WHERE [Part_Numbber] = @textInput";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("textInput", text);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "XML");

        if (count == 0)
        { 
            dc = ds.Clone();
            count ++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() != "NULL")
            {

                dc.Tables[0].ImportRow(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]);
            }
        }



        GridView1.DataSource = dc;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below code to append rows from 1 DT to other final DT. LikeWise

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt2.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr[0] = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[0]);
            dr[1] = dataRow[1].ToString();
            dr[2] = dataRow[2].ToString();
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt3.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr[0] = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[0]);
            dr[1] = dataRow[1].ToString();
            dr[2] = dataRow[2].ToString();
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt4.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr[0] = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[0]);
            dr[1] = dataRow[1].ToString();
            dr[2] = dataRow[2].ToString();
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Currently, the problem is the variable will be flash once I type in another value

Comment: If you think the above posted code gives you a solution then click on accept solution ...@rex